# SQL Query for "Usage" in 15 minutes intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have a digital Meter. This digital Meter puts it's metering Data into a (Postgres) Database. The relevant Data looks like this:

timestamp, total_m3

Every few seconds to minutes, I get the Data logged into the Database. So every 15 Minutes I have 0 to 100 entries in the Database.

The total_m3 Value is the incrementing meter value.

I'm looking for a select query to get:
Every 15 Minutes how much the meter was measuring.

For example:

```
2023-05-11 20:59:49.000000, 296.650
2023-05-11 20:50:49.000000, 296.650
2023-05-11 20:45:49.000000, 296.250
2023-05-11 20:37:49.000000, 296.150
2023-05-11 20:30:49.000000, 296.000
```

The Result should look like:

```
2023-05-11 21:00:00.000000, 0.4
2023-05-11 20:45:00.000000, 0.25
```

Would it be possible to do that in SQL? Or should I just say F* it, I code the logic into the App.

Comment: 1) Are just ignoring the seconds portion? As `2023-05-11 20:30:49.000000, 296.000` would be in the next 15 minute interval. 2) What values do you want to want to subtract? In other words if there are different values  for each reading in a 15 minute segment , which ones do you compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the date as intervall of 15 Minutes and use that to group by

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('minute', "dt") + interval '15 minute'
  - (CAST(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM "dt") AS integer) % 15) * interval '1 minute' AS trunc_15_minute


  ,MAX("value") - MIN("value") dff
FROM tabl1
GROUP BY trunc_15_minute
ORDER BY trunc_15_minute;
```

| trunc_15_minute | dff |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-11 20:45:00 | 0.150 |
| 2023-05-11 21:00:00 | 0.400 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-RWcgJKU)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Postgres 14 or higher, you can perform the 15 minutes truncation with [date function `date_bin()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN).

It is not obvious how you want to compute the meter difference.

If you are looking for the overall increase *within* the interval, the difference between the min and max values should give you the result you want:

```
select date_bin('15 minutes', ts, timestamp '2000-01-01') ts_15_min,
    max(total_m3) - min(total_m3) meter_increase
from mytable
group by 1
order by 1
```

Or maybe you want to compare the last value of the previous interval to the last value of the current interval. If so, we can use window functions:

```
select date_bin('15 minutes', ts, timestamp '2000-01-01') ts_15_min,
    max(total_m3) 
    - lag(max(total_m3), 1, min(total_m3)) over(order by date_bin('15 minutes', ts, timestamp '2000-01-01')) meter_increase
from mytable
group by 1
order by 1
```

Both queries assume that the meter value is always increasing, as explained in the question.

Note that I renamed the timestamp column to `ts`, so it does not clash with the corresponding SQL keyword.